# React-Hook-Form returns undefined evertime I try to upload image to it

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

So I have been trying to make a form for adding a student in my website and everything is registering correctly except for my picture.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import FormInputField from "../../Components/FormInputField/FormInputField";
import { AddStudent } from "../../Types";
import { AddStudentFormFields } from "../../strings";
import style from "./AddStudentForm.module.css";
import { doc, getFirestore, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
const AddAStudent = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState, reset } = useForm<AddStudent>();
  const onsubmit: SubmitHandler<AddStudent> = (data) => {
    console.log(data.newphotp.name);
    return;
    const db = getFirestore();
    const colRef = doc(db, "Students", data.UniversityID);
    setDoc(colRef, data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.isSubmitSuccessful) reset();
  }, [formState, reset]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form className={style.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onsubmit)}>
        <div>
          {AddStudentFormFields.map((item, index) => (
            <FormInputField
              key={index}
              register={register}
              name={item.field}
              label={item.label}
            />
          ))}
          <input type="file" {...register("newphotp")} />
        </div>

        <button className={style.button}>Add student </button>
        <button type="reset" className={style.button}>
          Reset form
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>

  );
};

export default AddAStudent;
```

I have tried to figure it out since an hour but it is not working sadly.
version of react-hook-form is 7.40.0

Comment: `console.log(data.newphotp)` and see what you've got

Answer (score 0):

The input of type file return an array of type file so this :

```
console.log(data.newphotp[0].name)
```

worked fine.